# wp8 app crashes after publishing

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-store

i published my windows phone 8 app yesterday , and it was working fine on my device and another device which i also used for developing , but user have reported that the app crashes , and it appears that the the app crashes after navigating from a home screen , but i am sure that every thing works fine on my device , first i thought i was a region problem , but i changed my device region and language and the app also works fine , note that the app i am trying on my device is the published version .

Comment: Can you specify what are the operations you are doing when you are navigating away from the home screen like DB creation Web service call etc?

Answer (score 0):

In your Windows Phone Developer dashboard, you should be able to look at the Crash count (unhandled exceptions) details of your App and also look at the stack trace.

Start from there and it should be a good pointer to the method/line faulting.